# how can i use pdo the php extension to make a query in mysql that uses a join (2 tables from different databases)?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

the thing is i have two tables in two different databases let's call them A and B.
in database A we have table1 and in database B we have table2. the primary key of table1 is a foreign key in table 2. So i need to use a join query to extract data from the two databases in the same time. Or using PDO you can not connect to two databases using the same pdo object !

$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=A', 'root', '12345');

so what can i do ?

Comment: Export/import the table into the other database?

Comment: Is the Database on another host? E.g. not localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN otherDB.t2 on otherDB.t2.t1_fk = t1.id
```

Provided the user has relevant permissions.

Comment: the problem is not the query ! the problem is how can i connect to two databases using the same PDO object ? cause as u can see i'm connected to just one database $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=A', 'root', '12345'); . If i have to use two objects how can i do that ?

Comment: Out of interest have you tried running a query in that format? My understanding is the dbname param is more of guide than for the purpose of containing your query.

Comment: ya I've tried and the result is Access denied for user. well i was expecting it.

Comment: well it was just a mistake in the name of my user.